# Keep mmenu open on desktop version

Tags: javascript, jquery, mmenu

I want to keep the mmenu open when using a browser on a desktop computer but it closes after i click on a area thats not fin the menu.

```
                    "counters": true,
                    "offCanvas": true,
                    "onClick": {
                        "close": true
                    },
                    "extensions": [
                   //     "pagedim-black",
                        "theme-dark",
                        "custom-width"
                    ],
                    "iconbar": {
                        "use": true,
                        "top": [
                            "<a href='#/'><i class='fa fa-home'></i></a>",
                            "<a href='#/'><i class='fa fa-user'></i></a>"
                        ],
                        "bottom": [
                            "<a href='#/'><i class='fa fa-twitter'></i></a>",
                            "<a href='#/'><i class='fa fa-facebook'></i></a>",
                            "<a href='#/'><i class='fa fa-linkedin'></i></a>"
                        ]
                    }
                });
                var API = $("#menu").data("mmenu");
                API.open();
```

already tried with the offcanvas setting, but then API.open is not recognized.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set different mmenu options by screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258631/how-do-i-set-different-mmenu-options-by-screen-size)

Comment: No it doesn't, the menu shouldn't be closed at all times